# Fails to execute index action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a problem in MVC ASP.NET project.
i work with LINQ technology.When i want to insert one record to table,this error is shown.although insert action is preformed:**

ERROR:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The
>   parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(Int32)' in
>   'MVCJahan_oil.Controllers.getehController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.

controller methods for insert(create):

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var query= from gete in l_class.getehs where gete.request_no == id select gete;
    this.Session["req_no"] = id; 
    return View(query.ToList());
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "id")]geteh gte)
{
    try
    {

        l_class.getehs.InsertOnSubmit(gte);
        l_class.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = System.Convert.ToInt32  (Session["req_no"].ToString()) });
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to update your question title to be a bit more descriptive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in the controller method that is called after the insert is performed.  The method is expecting an `int id` parameter, but the redirect that is routed to the method isn't passing an id value.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is expecting an `int` named `id`, and not getting one. If the integer is nullable, then you should use an `int?` parameter instead.

Instead of

```
public ActionResult Index(int id) {
}
```

you should use

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id) {
}
```

instead.

If the id should be there and you're use a PRG pattern, be sure to include the id when redirecting after the form submission by using `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = 1 });` (only replace the 1 with the real value).

Comment: Thank you. but my problem not solved.please answer me with attention to changes in my question.

Comment: Just to add to this, the problem you have is your *Index* method requires a non-nullable parameter (id) and you are not setting it as @Jarret rightly pointed out. When you go to the URL e.g. MySite/MyController it will call the Index action in MyController, which in your case would through the above exception because it **requires** an integer parameter. You need to either a) change your id parameter in the Index action to be nullable or b) always pass an id in the URL e.g. MySite/MyController/MyID

Comment: @Bahareh, I explained in my last comment what needs to be done. You either update your Index method to have a nullable parameter (see @Jarrett's answer) or you make sure you always pass in the ID when you are navigating to that particular action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RedirectToAction(new {controller="Home", action="Index", id=123});
```

Replace the controller, action and id by yourself.
If the error still occurs, please check your session's value.